# How to display certain parts of a list ? (Python)

Tags: python

The basic salary is the third element of each object.

```
employee_list = []

sales1 = SalesEmployee('1001', 'Alex', 2000.00, 20000.00, 8.00)
sales2 = SalesEmployee('1002', 'Mark', 1800.00, 22000.00, 6.00)
sales3 = SalesEmployee('1003', 'Fiona', 2500.00, 16000.00, 5.00) 

part1 = PartTimeEmployee('2001', 'Anna', 0.00, 100.00, 8.00)
part2 = PartTimeEmployee('2002', 'Ben', 0.00, 120.00, 9.00)
part3 = PartTimeEmployee('2003', 'John', 0.00, 110.00, 7.00)

employee_list.append(sales1)
employee_list.append(sales2)
employee_list.append(sales3)
employee_list.append(part1)
employee_list.append(part2)
employee_list.append(part3)
```

How do i display the all the employee details without showing the part time employees' basic salary.

Comment: What is the diffrent between part time and full time employee in your problem ?

Comment: for sales employee, the attribute is id, name, basic salary, sales, commission rate

for part time employee, the attribute is id, name, basic salary, hours worked, hourly rate

Comment: What is the type of `SalesEmployee` and `PartTimeEmployee` ? Class Object ?

Comment: Isn't the problem 'how to display certain attributes of an instance ?' instead of 'how to display certain parts of a list ?'.

Comment: ooh sorry used the wrong word.

Answer (score 0):

if SalesEmployee and PartTimeEmployee has the same super class, define a function to display information

within this function, use typeof() to see if an object is SalesEmployee or PartTimeEmployee, then display information accordingly.

```
class Employee
def show:
    if(typeof(self) == PartTimeEmployee):
        print/return blabla
    elif(type(self) == SalesEmployee):
        print/return blabla
```

something like this

when you want to display info, iterate each element in the list with show